# Axios request body are parsed strangely in the express server

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have `nodejs` express server and `nodejs` `axios` client, I tried send  post data with `x-www-form-urlencoded` header.

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => { 
   const { username, password } = req.body
   console.log(req.body) 
 })
```

request body from nodejs axios client:

```
{ '{"username":"gefalko","password":"mypass"}': '' }
```

request body from postman client:

```
{"username":"gefalko","password":"mypass"}
```

---

I use 'body-parser'  https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser middleware for request body parsing on the server.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

and my `axios` code looks like:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const prompt = require('prompt')

var prompt_attributes = [
    {
        name: 'username',
        validator: /^[a-zA-Z\s\-]+$/,
        warning: 'Username is not valid, it can only contains letters, spaces, or dashes'
    },
    {
        name: 'password',
        hidden: true
    }
]

prompt.start();

prompt.get(prompt_attributes, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return 1;
    }else {
        console.log('Command-line received data:');
        const username = result.username
        const password = result.password

        const config = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
        }

        const reqBody =  {
          username: username,
          password: password
        }

        axios.post('http://localhost:3005/login', reqBody, config).then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: With `x-www-form-urlencoded` server parses payload assuming other format, not json. Use `application/json` instead.

Comment: Ah okay i have seen it from your last question, if you do `axios.post(url, object)` json will be send, if you do `axios.post(url, string)` then `x-www-form-urlencoded` will be send.    if you manualy change the content-type header to `x-www-form-urlencoded` it won't change the fact that you are sending json.

Comment: I would recomend just getting rid of the `config`, so `axios.post('http://localhost:3005/login', reqBody)`, then the data will be send as json, and your express server is able to handle json.